# Why it is not reading second line?

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I'm having problem with a communication from server to my android application, basiclly the communication goes like this:

```
1. send x and y
2. get the list of coordinates from server
3. send "ok"
4. receive titles string
```

everything goes smooth till the last line, I know it is sending properly because it works with telnet, but my android application does not receive a thing. Here is the code for sending and receiving from client:

```
    clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 1234);
    Log.d("LatitudeE6", ""+point.getLatitudeE6());
    Log.d("LongitudeE6", ""+point.getLongitudeE6());
    os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    sentenceX = ""+point.getLatitudeE6();
    sentenceY = ""+point.getLongitudeE6();
    os.println(sentenceX + " "+ sentenceY+'\n');

    String thing =is.readLine();
    String [] holder = thing.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println("thing printed: " +thing);

    os.println("ok\n");
    String test = is.readLine();
    System.out.println("tester: " +test); // this doesn' work
```

server:

```
try{
    in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ms.connector();
        while(true){
        line = in.readLine();

        if(line.startsWith("51789181 19426953")==true){ 
// these are the coordinates, if the client sends them, it will receive  the list of other coordinates
        os.println(ms.lister().toString().replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').trim().replace(',', ' ') +""+'\n');
        os.flush();

         }else if ( line.equals("ok")==true) {
                     os.flush();
                       os.println(ms.topicDesc().toString().replace('[', ' ').replace(']', ' ').trim().replace(',', ' ') +""+'\n');
                 }
    }
catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you sent a line break after the OK, and flushed the socket, at the server end?

Comment: I've just add the '\n' after "ok" and flush the socket, but it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote my comment before - are you sending a line break after the titles string on the other side? Please show the server code.

Comment: Yes flush() everywhere. ("== true" can be left out.)

Comment: with flush() or without - it doesn't make any difference in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending two newline characters, one via `os.println()` and the other via `"\n"`. This translates to two lines od data. On the client side you are just reading one line via `readLine()`. YOu do this multiple times on server and client.

Try removing `"\n"` from your sending code on both client and server.